# glmer warning message, Model nearly unidentifiable

Tags: r, warnings, lme4

I'm trying to run a model on plant survival between multiple sites. My model is as follows:

`model <- glmer(Plant_per_plot ~ Site * seeding_depth + (1|Site:Pair), data=Marina_Survival, family = "poisson")`

Plant_per_plot is numerical, the rest are all factors. Site has 5 levels, seeding_depth 2 levels and Pair has 4 levels. I can run the model and summary analysis returns results however I keep getting the following error message when I run the model:

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

I've been looking over Stackoverflow for people with the same error message but I've not been able to find an instance that's the same as mine. Most others additional error messages, and I can't decipher which part of the solution is related to which error message.

As I'm trying to create an optimal model I'm also playing around with updating the model.

`model1.2 <- update(model, .~.- Site:depth)`

However this just returns more error messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

Are these messages related or is there more wrong within my data?
I hope someone can explain what is going wrong here, I'm happy to post additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Had to many 0 values in the data, after removing sites which had no data points the error message disappeared.